# Verb + gerundive or Verb + infinitive, what is preferable?

Tags: verbs, gerunds, complementation

What is preferable to use: *verb + gerundive* or *verb + infinitive*?

For example:

`I tried checking it`

or

`I tried to check it`

if both are possible then what's the difference? Are there any specific use cases for both *gerundive* and *infinitive* in such a construction?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try + gerund means to experiment with an action that might be a solution to your problem.

> If you have problems sleeping, you could try **doing** some yoga before you go to bed, or you could try **drinking** some warm milk.

Try + to-infinitive means to make an effort to do something. It may be something very difficult or even impossible:

> The surgeons tried **to save** his life but he died on the operating table.

You can find info on usage of *try* and other verbs that can take gerund/infinitive in different sources, e.g. [here](http://www.englishpage.com/gerunds/gerund_or_infinitive_different_list.htm), or [here](http://www.edufind.com/english/grammar/gerund_or_infinitive2.php).

Comment: @RuslanGerasimov Note, however, that these interpretations are specific to the verb *try*. Other verbs use gerunds and infinitives differently.

Comment: @StoneyB yes, that's clear from your answer, because links you provide shows that. Thanks for that.

Comment: @RuslanGerasimov Not my answer - Vilmar's. And a very good one, too!

Comment: @StoneyB correct.

Comment: Is it *sleeping problems?* or *problems sleeping!*