# try+gerund/infinitive (Difference in meaning)

Tags: infinitives, gerunds

1. I tried **to open** the door.
2. I tried **opening** the door

We can use both infinitive and gerund with verb "try" as used in above sentences. Does it change the meaning of the  sentence if use gerund or infinitive?.(here i don't know if the meaning of sentences is changed.)

The same confusion arise in these two sentences. 
1.I stopped **seeing** him. 2. I stopped **to see** him.(But in case of these two sentence i know the meaning is changed but don't know exactly what the change is).

Answer (score 17):

The difference in your first pair, with *try*, is addressed [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/38981/32).

- *Try to VERB* means “attempt to accomplish the action of VERB”.

  > I tried to open the door = *I attempted to cause the door to become open*.

  If the attempt succeeds, the action of *VERB* is accomplished: the door is open. If the attempt fails, the action is not accomplished: the door is still closed.
- *Try VERBing* means “perform the action of VERB to find out if it will accomplish some other purpose”.

  > I wanted to clear the smoke from the room, so I tried opening the door = *I opened the door in order to clear the smoke from the room*.

  The action of *VERB* is presumed to be accomplished. If the attempt succeeds, the purpose is accomplished: the smoke is cleared. if the attempt fails, the action is accomplished but the purpose is not: although the door is open, the smoke remains.

In both of these, the clause with *VERB* is the **complement** of *TRY*. This is not the case with *STOP*: *STOP* only takes gerund complements. However, it may take an infinitival **adjunct** describing the reason for stopping:

> I stopped seeing him = *I ceased to see him; I no longer saw him*.
>
> I stopped to see him = *I stopped in order to see him; I ceased doing what I was doing* or *I made a stop in my trip so that I might see him*.

Answer (score 1):

- Trying opening the door is "trying a technique" intending to try a "process" that might succeed.
- Trying to open is performing an "action" regardless of any previous try.

> I tried to kill the wolf but it escaped. Later, I tried poisoning it, trapping it and shooting it with a gun but nothing worked.

Shall I try *calling* the police / *to call* the police? Choose the correct answer now ;)

Comment: It should be "Shall I try to call the police? Am I right?