# "Spending more time TRYING....." and "Spending more time TO TRY....."

Tags: meaning, infinitive-vs-gerund

Is there any difference in meaning between "*Spending more time **trying** to.....*" and "*Spending more time **to try** to.....*"?

Below is the headline of an online news article I just read this morning, and I am wondering if the **"trying"** in the sentence is interchangeable with **"to try"** without changing any meaning of the entire sentence. If not, what's the difference?

> ["Spending more time trying to fall asleep rather than actually
> sleeping? You're not alone."](https://www.healthline.com/health/healthy-sleep/fall-asleep-fast)

Comment: Closely related **1.** [Difference between "try to do" and "try doing"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/226546) **2** [What is the differences between 'try to' and 'try to+verb' and 'try + verb'?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/79213/what-is-the-differences-between-try-to-and-try-toverb-and-try-verb) **3** [try+gerund/infinitive (Difference in meaning)](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/44160) **4** [Verb + gerundive or Verb + infinitive, what is preferable?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/30970)

Comment: Thank you, Mari-Lou A, for your input, but the point of my question actually has nothing to do with neither "try doing" nor "try to do".  Let me quote two sample sentences to explain my point. 1) Are you spending hours to fall asleep?  2) Are you spending hours falling asleep?     Do these two sentences sound same?

Comment: 'Trying' present participle. As in 'I am trying to fall asleep'.  Try Verb.  'I have been spending more time to try to fall asleep'. Whereas 'Spending more time trying to' mixes the past and present tenses up.

Comment: `the point of my question actually has nothing to do with neither "try doing" nor "try to do". ` You could've fooled me! I read, ***I am wondering if the "trying" in the sentence is interchangeable with "to try" without changing any meaning of the entire sentence*** in your question

Comment: To Mari-Lou A:   My point was rather the difference between "to try (to+verb)" and "trying (verb+ing)", not the difference between "try+gerund" and "try+infinitive". You can even forget about the word "try". Let me quote another example sentence. "Spending a couple of hours falling (or to fall) asleep?"

Comment: The issue is not about _try_. It's about what complement the phrase _spend time_ takes: it overwhelmingly takes an _-ing_ clause rather than a _"to" infinitive_ clause. I've voted to reopen, because the closure was on a faulty argument.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I see it, the difference is one of emphasis:

> Spending more time trying to […]

This suggests that you are continually trying to achieve your aim, throughout the whole period of time.

> Spending more time to try to […]

This suggests that you are taking extra time in order to increase your chance of achieving your aim.

So the former focusses on your *actions* (successful or not), while the latter focusses on the *intended result* (regardless of what you're doing to achieve it).

In the quoted headline, the ‘trying to’ highlights the process — the lying awake, fretting — rather than the result, and allows for the possibility that the attempt might be ultimately unsuccessful.

Answer (score 2):

In this specific case, you cannot switch out the word "trying" with "to try" because the sentence has parallel structure. [This article](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/parallelism/) might do a better job explaining than I, but, basically, the two sides of "rather than" should have identical grammatical structure. Since "to try" is infinitive and "trying" is a gerund, only "trying" fits with "sleeping."

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. It is quite understandable, but what if the sentence does not include the parallel structure like the below one? Can the "trying" be switchable to "to try" or not?

"Spending an hour or two trying to fall asleep? You're not alone."